# Compare a specific data with table records using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, foreach

i wanna Compare a Text with the all records in a table in the database 
i wanna do it using Foreach or For loop 
as if there is any mail in the database that similar to the one the user enter 
i wanna enter the data of the Customer and before he make save i wanna make sure that this customer is not already in the data base 
MSSQL server 2005
i am Coding by LINQ

Comment: What database do you mean? Microsoft SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try:

```
    IDataReader rd; // Get rd as a DataReader
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        // Compare data here
    }
    rd.Close();
```

I mean: if you read data you need with a query (returning a `IDataReader`) you can go trough each record and do what you need.

Comment: As @Muad'Dib says, using SQL would be really faster. You must see if your comparison is too difficult to write in a query or not...

Answer (score 0):

why not use SQL to do it? it would be way more efficient and, thus, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I achieved something similar using `IF NOT EXISTS` in my Stored Proc.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT YourField FROM YourTable WHERE YourField = SomeValue)
INSERT INTO Table ... VALUES ...
```

Perhaps this might point you in the right direction.